# Fire icon on hover

Tags: html, css

im trying to fire a class when a hover a button, basically inside of my href i have a i icon tag that needs to change color: but is not working:

my css and html:

```css
.catalog-icons i:hover{
   color: #ba658a;
}

.catalog-icons .btn-icon:hover ~.catalog-icons i:hover{
    color:#ba658a;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">
  <a class="btn btn-icon" href="">
    <i class="fontello-icon icon-vet"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also, your code is not complete, please provide full code. Do you want to change the color of the icon when the link hovers?

Comment: "Fire another div on hover"? Your code contains no `divs`.

Comment: sorry, i mean icon i

Comment: @Irandoust yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

I added an image since your code does not provide any.
Your rule should be simple:

```
.your_hovered_element_class:hover affected_elemnt_inside
```

in your case once `.btn-icon` is hovered, you change the `i` background color

```css
.btn-icon:hover i{
  background-color: #ba658a;
}

i img {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-inline-item">
  <a class="btn btn-icon" href="">link text
    <i class="fontello-icon icon-vet"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-person-outline-128.png" /></i>
  </a>
</li>
```